# Windows 10 Home remote TCP connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, tcpip

The question may sound obvious, but I cannot connect to open TCP port on Windows 10 Home on my home network.

My devices: 
PC1 - Windows 10 Home (with Ubuntu 14 installed as a second OS) 
PC2 - Windows 8.1

To test connectivity, I do the following: 
- run "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" on PC1 (this opens local HTTP server on port 8000 to browse filesystem) 
- open http://[PC1 ip]:8000/ on PC1 - works as expected. 
- connect PC2 to the same local WiFi network. 
- open http://[PC2 ip]:8000/ on PC2 - connection timeout.

I have tried different things to troubleshoot: 
- added wifi network to "private" on both PC1 and PC2 
- turned off the firewall on both PC1 and PC2 
- turned on the firewall on PC1 with the rule "allow inbound connections on port 8000" 
- turned off Windows Defender on both PC1 and PC2 
- disabled (and then uninstalled) antivirus on PC1

PING does not work in either direction, too. From PC2, Wireshark shows SYN attempts to PC1 with no response. Though I see ARP packets go here and there and IP address resolves to MAC correctly.

If I run Ubuntu on PC1, everything works perfectly. I wonder if there any kind of limitation on "Home" edition of Windows that disallows inbound TCP connects?

Comment: `netstat -abn -proto tcp` in an elevated cmd to check that you are actually listening on the correct IP address (either your local network address or `0.0.0.0` should work; `127.0.0.1` won't).

Comment: thank you for your response, I do see listening on 0.0.0.0. But still, cannot connect.

Comment: When you say you uninstalled antivirus - what software were you using? It's common for antivirus programs to silently drop all incoming connection attempts. Can you try turning off Windows Firewall entirely, just to test?